Firefox: arrow key does not count as user gesture, so cannt play AudioContext
I'm writing a game where the player interacts using the arrow keys, which can produce audio. This works in all browsers, except Firefox.
Firefox does not seem to count the arrow keys (ArrowUp, ArrowLeft, ArrowRight, ArrowDown) as valid user gestures, which prevents an audio context from being played. Firefox counts other keys (such as W/A/S/D) as valid, but not the arrow keys.
The following error is printed in the console:

An AudioContext was prevented from starting automatically. It must be created or resumed after a user gesture on the page.

However, arrow keys are treated as a user gesture in Chrome and Safari, and the audio plays fine.
Is there any known cross-browser solution or workaround that I could use? I know I could just put a button at the start of my game, but my artistic vision of the game just doesn't have a big start button before you can play.
Perhaps this is a known Firefox bug and I just can't find it, or perhaps somebody knows a workaround.
TLDR:
Steps to reproduce:

Go to the demo site
Press ArrowUp/Down/Left/Right

Expected result: sound will be played in all browsers
Actual result: sound is only played in Safari and Chrome, not Firefox
Demo code:
<code>press a key to see if it sounds: </code>
<script>
    const code = document.querySelector('code')
    const audioCtx = new AudioContext({})
    const oscillatorGainNode = audioCtx.createGain()
    oscillatorGainNode.gain.value = 0.2
    oscillatorGainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination)

    const beep = () => {
        const oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator()
        oscillator.type = "square"
        oscillator.frequency.value = 220 + ((Math.random() * 9) | 0) * 32
        const msDelay = 0
        const msDuration = 200

        oscillatorGainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination)

        oscillator.connect(oscillatorGainNode)
        oscillator.start(audioCtx.currentTime + msDelay / 1000)
        oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + msDelay / 1000 + msDuration / 1000)
    }

    window.onkeydown = (ev=> {
        beep()
        code.textContent+=ev.key + ' '
    })
</script>

The demo is also hosted at this URL:
https://6643defaf1a25706487ec3f8--glittery-dusk-6bb447.netlify.app/
I have reported this as Firefox bug #1897649 - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1897649

The simplest solution is always to load the game with a "click to start" UI of any kind.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans in the question it says "I know I could just put a button at the start of my game" - in fact, as a workaround right now if the user agent includes Firefox in my game it will start paused and require either press of P or a click of the button to start the game (which counts as user action) - the question is asking about a better workaround, if one exists

I think this can be considered a bug in Firefox. The spec (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#user-activation-processing-model) includes the following text:

An activation triggering input event is any event whose isTrusted
attribute is true and whose type is one of:
"keydown", provided the key is neither the Esc key nor a shortcut key reserved by the user agent;
...

Maybe one could argue that the arrow keys could be seen as shortcut keys because they sometimes allow to navigate form fields.

I've reported this as a bug to Mozilla here already: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1897649 - I updated the original question to showthis.The current state of discussion is the Firefox team disallow ArrowUp/Left/Right/Down because they're non printable characters - but ArrowUp/Down mainly for scrolling through articles
